In Swiftui, is there a way to get the id / position of a grid's cell using onTapGesture or any other technique?
I am trying to learn SwiftUI by converting my personal Android apps. I am initially prototyping the interfaces. I have coded a LazyVGrid. I want to be able to tap on a "cell" and be able to determine the Id that I assigned to that cell/view or the row and column of that cell/view in order to manipulate the data displayed. This app is to run on an iPhone so, to my understanding, a table would not display all of my columns.
'''
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
init() {
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    
    appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [
        .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)]
    
    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
}


private var columns = [GridItem(.fixed(120), spacing: 0),
                       GridItem(.fixed(52), spacing: 0),
                       GridItem(.fixed(52), spacing: 0),
                       GridItem(.fixed(52), spacing: 0),
                       GridItem(.fixed(52), spacing: 0),
                       GridItem(.fixed(52), spacing: 0)]

@State var gridData: [String] = []

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach((0..<gridData.count), id: \.self) {
                    let width: CGFloat = $0%6 == 0 ? 120 : 52
                    let alignment: Alignment = $0%6 == 0 ? .leading : .center
                    Text(gridData[$0]).padding(.horizontal, 4)
                        .frame(width: width, height: 30, alignment: alignment)
                     .border(Color.black)
                }
            }.onTapGesture {
                print("tapped ")
            }
        }.task {
            gridData = setupGridData()
    }.navigationTitle("Tee Time Administration").fontWeight(.light)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Image(systemName: "gear")
            }
        }
}

}
'''


Move the .onTapGesture{...} up to the Text(gridData[$0]), then
use the index ($0) to calculate its position in the grid.
Simple geometry, columns and rows in a 2D Cartesian grid.

To identify the item of a tap, try this approach using use a specific struct GridData
and moving the .onTapGesture{...} to the Text.
This avoid using index in the ForEach which is considered unsafe and bad practice
in SwiftUI.
Example code:
struct GridData: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let value: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    private var columns = [GridItem(.fixed(120), spacing: 0),
                           GridItem(.fixed(52), spacing: 0),
                           GridItem(.fixed(52), spacing: 0),
                           GridItem(.fixed(52), spacing: 0),
                           GridItem(.fixed(52), spacing: 0),
                           GridItem(.fixed(52), spacing: 0)]

    let gridData: [GridData] = [GridData(value: "banana"),GridData(value: "a0"), GridData(value: "b0"), GridData(value: "c0"),GridData(value: "d0"),GridData(value: "e0"),
     GridData(value: "apple"),GridData(value: "a1"), GridData(value: "b1"), GridData(value: "c1"),GridData(value: "d1"),GridData(value: "e1"),
     GridData(value: "orange"),GridData(value: "a2"), GridData(value: "b2"), GridData(value: "c2"),GridData(value: "d2"),GridData(value: "e2"),
     GridData(value: "mango"),GridData(value: "a3"), GridData(value: "b3"), GridData(value: "c3"),GridData(value: "d3"),GridData(value: "e3")]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(gridData) { data in
                        Text(data.value).padding(6)
                            .border(Color.black)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                print("--> data: \(data)")
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

EDIT-1:
Here is an basic example code to get the (x,y) grid position when tapping
on a grid item. To get the item of the tap, just use gridData[index] as shown.
Note using index in ForEach is considered bad coding practice.
I cannot remember the exact place, but some Apple WWDC emphasize the importance of using Identifiable instead of index range, for various reasons, such as efficiency, stability (no out-of-range). The SO community has also mentioned this many times.
Here is an example code that uses index range:
struct ContentView: View {
    let columns = [GridItem(.fixed(120), spacing: 0),
                           GridItem(.fixed(52), spacing: 0),
                           GridItem(.fixed(52), spacing: 0),
                           GridItem(.fixed(52), spacing: 0),
                           GridItem(.fixed(52), spacing: 0),
                           GridItem(.fixed(52), spacing: 0)]
    
    let gridData: [String] = ["banana","a0", "b0", "c0","d0","e0",
                              "apple","a1", "b1", "c1","d1","e1",
                              "orange","a2", "b2", "c2","d2","e2",
                              "mango","a3", "b3", "c3","d3","e3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(0..<gridData.count, id: \.self) { index in
                        let width: CGFloat = index%6 == 0 ? 120 : 52
                        let alignment: Alignment = index%6 == 0 ? .leading : .center
                        Text(gridData[index]).padding(4)
                            .frame(width: width, height: 30, alignment: alignment)
                            .border(Color.black)
                            // --- here
                            .onTapGesture {
                                let x = index % columns.count
                                let y = index / columns.count
                                print("--> cell:  (x: \(x), y: \(y))")
                                print("--> value: \(gridData[index])")
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

EDIT-2:
For a stable ForEach, you can combine the two approaches (Identifiable and index range), such as:
 struct GridData: Identifiable {
     let id = UUID()
     let value: String
 }

 struct ContentView: View {

     let columns = [GridItem(.fixed(120), spacing: 0),
                            GridItem(.fixed(52), spacing: 0),
                            GridItem(.fixed(52), spacing: 0),
                            GridItem(.fixed(52), spacing: 0),
                            GridItem(.fixed(52), spacing: 0),
                            GridItem(.fixed(52), spacing: 0)]

     let gridData: [GridData] = [GridData(value: "banana"),GridData(value: "a0"), GridData(value: "b0"), GridData(value: "c0"),GridData(value: "d0"),GridData(value: "e0"),
      GridData(value: "apple"),GridData(value: "a1"), GridData(value: "b1"), GridData(value: "c1"),GridData(value: "d1"),GridData(value: "e1"),
      GridData(value: "orange"),GridData(value: "a2"), GridData(value: "b2"), GridData(value: "c2"),GridData(value: "d2"),GridData(value: "e2"),
      GridData(value: "mango"),GridData(value: "a3"), GridData(value: "b3"), GridData(value: "c3"),GridData(value: "d3"),GridData(value: "e3")]
     
     var body: some View {
         NavigationStack {
             ScrollView {
                 LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 0) {
                     // --- here
                     ForEach(Array(gridData.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, item in
                         let width: CGFloat = index%6 == 0 ? 120 : 52
                         let alignment: Alignment = index%6 == 0 ? .leading : .center
                         Text(item.value).padding(6)
                             .frame(width: width, height: 30, alignment: alignment)
                             .border(Color.black)
                             .onTapGesture {
                                 let x = index % columns.count
                                 let y = index / columns.count
                                 print("--> cell:  (x: \(x), y: \(y))")
                                 print("--> value: \(item.value)")
                             }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }


I knew my intentions but I did not state them clearly. I apologize. My goal was not to get the contents of "cell", in your example, "Mango" or "a3", but to get the position of the cell in the grid. That was to be step one. Not stated, was that after accomplishing step one, I needed to figure out a way, based on the position, whether to navigate to one of several new views or not.  But I do have a follow up question. What is wrong with using "index" in a Foreach?

updated my answer to get the position of the cell in the grid, using index range in the ForEach as you want.

did my answer not worked for you?

Yes, thank you.  I went with having each cell as a button but using the onTapGesture would work just the same.
